# ¿Que error tengo en este programa de c++?

Tags: c++

el código pide un entero n y tiene que poner todos los números del n asta el cero en decremento, en diferentes filas y si es múltiplo del 5 poner la palabra Beep:

(n=7)
7
6
5
Beep
4
3
2
1

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    int main(){
        int n;
        int x;
        cin >> n;
        for (int x=n; x>0; x--){
            if(x%5 = 0){
            cout<< x << endl <<"Beep"<<endl;
            }
            else{
            cout << x <<endl;   
            }
        }
        return x;}
```

Comment: En la condición debes poner == no =, estas comparando, no asignando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que tienes es que ese programa ni siquiera compila, esta instrucción da un fallo de compilación:

```
x%5 = 0
```

Esa instrucción se compone de dos partes, la primera es calcular el resto de dividir el valor de la variable `x` entre cinco, la segunda es igualar dicho resultado a cero. Obviamente fallará porque los resultados de operaciones no pueden cambiar su valor: Imagina que `x` es tres, el residuo sería tres y tres no puede igualarse a cero... de hecho tres no puede igualarse a nada; tres es tres.

Lo que querías hacer es una comparación, no una igualación:

```
x%5 == 0
```

Con esa corrección, indentando bien el código y eliminando instrucciones innecesarias, tu programa podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace std;

        int numero;
        cin >> numero;

        for (; numero; --numero) {
        cout << numero << (!(numero % 5) ? " Beep\n": "\n");
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3LCsIwEEXXzVdcK0K6KOhCBFMq@B1uQhpLwExCHivpt0ertc5iuPfMwFHet6NSpWwNqUceNDrjYgpa2p4xQwlWGuINnqzK0dAIklZHL5VGTINgDMvMv5StDk6sTBlC36945XcXwMWPo22/6WOplMsJXbdc58Q3fCk7HBtcUOOqtb9RfUb93s3fOP0lQaccCHvBplIOJ/YC)</kbd>.